# Is it possible to connect remotely to mysql server on android phone

Tags: mariadb, remote-access, termux

I am trying to connect remotely to mysql server which is on an android device in termux. According to mariadb's official website https://mariadb.com/kb/en/configuring-mariadb-for-remote-client-access/:
"Alternatively, just add the following lines at the end of your .my.cnf (notice that the file name starts with a dot) file in your home directory or alternative last in your /etc/my.cnf file.

/etc/my.cnf:

```
# 
# This group is read both by the client and the server 
# use it for options that affect everything 
# [client-server] 
# 
# include *.cnf from the config directory 
# !includedir /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/etc/my.cnf 
[mysqld] 
skip-networking = 0 
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
```

I added these lines at the end of my.cnf file and restarted mysql service on termux but still unable to connect from remote location.
So my question is that is there any limitation on termux (android phone) to connect only locally, or I am missing something?

> C:\Users\USER>mysql -u USERNAME -h IP_ADDRESS -p Enter password:
> *********** ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'IP_ADDRESS' (10060)

Comment: In stead of `skip-bind-address`, use: `bind-address = 0.0.0.0`  (Still searching for the q/a on stackoverflow, because this must have been asked before... , but cannot find it now)

Comment: I also tried to look for the similar question but failed. After replacing skip-bind-address with bind-address = 0.0.0.0, I am still not able to connect.

Comment: Can you share the contents of `/etc/my.cnf` and the contents form `.my.cnf` , togethere with the version of MariaDB you are using?

Comment: /etc/my.cnf:
#
# This group is read both by the client and the server
# use it for options that affect everything
#
[client-server]

#
# include *.cnf from the config directory
#
!includedir /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/etc/my.cnf
[mysqld]
skip-networking = 0
bind-address = 0.0.0.0

I am using MariaDB version 2:10.11.3 and I could not find .my.cnf file. I tried to find with the find command ".../com.termux/files $ find -name '.my.cnf'" and the result is empty.

Comment: mariadb  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.11.3-MariaDB, for Android (aarch64) using  EditLine wrapper

Comment: Default value for `skip-networking` is OFF, so you can delete that line (There is no ned for it)., see: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_skip_networking

Comment: Can you access the server locally? If you can you should find out if there is a firewall.... (I am running out of options here  )

Comment: Yes I can access the server locally. I didn't find any firewall/antivirus on the android phone.

Comment: When I ping in termux it sends and receive packets successfully to the client machine, but pinging in client machine to termux (server) times out with the result "100% loss". Is there any setting/utility in termux which needs to be set?

Comment: Please do some research on that subject: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ping+times+out

Answer (score -1):

After some research I have finally found the solution here
https://parzibyte.me/blog/2019/03/26/configurar-servidor-mysql-mariadb-android-conexiones-remotas/

The solution is to create a file my.cnf in the directory my.cnf.d (which is located in usr/etc directory) with the following contents:

`[mysqld]`
`bind-address = 0.0.0.0`
`port = 3306`

After creating and saving the file, restart the mariadb daemon.